# can not run make to install sdricoh_cs-0.1.3 driver

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, drivers

Ubuntu is not detecting my laptop's SD card reader. Running `lspci` returns the following about the device:

```
SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter
```

Reading about similar problems, it was suggested to download and install the driver from:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sdricohcs/?source=typ_redirect

But when I try and run `make`

I get the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-51-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/mo/Downloads/sdricoh_cs-0.1.4 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-51-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/mo/Downloads/sdricoh_cs-0.1.4/sdricoh_cs.o
/home/mo/Downloads/sdricoh_cs-0.1.4/sdricoh_cs.c:34:29: fatal error: pcmcia/cs_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcmcia/cs_types.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/mo/Downloads/sdricoh_cs-0.1.4/sdricoh_cs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mo/Downloads/sdricoh_cs-0.1.4] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-51-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: That looks like it is expecting to build a kernel module. Do you have the appropriate kernel header installed?

Comment: the output of my uname-r is 3.16.0-51-generic
so I did
 sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-51-generic

but this did not fix the problem.
The README file for the driver mentions the need to install
kernel-default >= 2.6.18
gcc
make
kernel-source
kernel-syms

so I started reading comments in 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/159833/how-do-i-get-the-kernel-source-code

But I'm not sure if its relevant to my original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems was resolved by allocating a file system for the SD card. In Ubuntu:

1- Go to Disks
2- Locate the SD card
3- Under volumes go to more actions
4- Click on Edit File System
5- Choosing FAT32 made the SD card appear under devices